# How do I change the cursor of a control in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey, mouse-cursor

I've created an [FMX GUI App](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) and I have several components on the form. I'd like to change the default `Cursor` for them, but I'm not sure how.

I've tried doing the following code to change the `Cursor` on my `Memo`:

```
self.Memo1.Cursor = "crNo"
```

But `self.Memo1.Cursor = "crNo"` doesn't work. I get `Error: Invalid class typecast`

What is the correct way to change the `Cursor` of a component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've discovered how to do it. I just needed to take out the quotes ("). This works:

```
self.Memo1.Cursor = crNo
```

You can also use the integer value for it like @5eb mentioned and that works too:

```
self.Memo1.Cursor = -18
```

Comment: Cursors are variables defined by Delphi. Have a look here: https://github.com/Embarcadero/python4delphi/blob/07099a703e630b404445dbc8e6a508b9717408fa/Source/WrapDelphiTypes.pas#L126

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out and inspected the value of `Memo1.Cursor` and got `-4`. So I think that explains the invalid type cast error. It's expecting an integer
and you're setting it to a string.

I looked at the FMX sourcecode and `crNo` is defined as a constant set to the value `TCursor(-18)`.

Seeing this I tried `self.Memo1.Cursor = -18` and got the `crNo` cursor.

I'm not sure if this is the intendend way to do it or if you can import the constant from somewhere like in FMX.